# opencv_core2410.dll - Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my code:

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
int main(){
    IplImage * image =  cvLoadImage("digital_image_processing.jpg");
    cvShowImage("Dung image", image);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow("Dung image");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of visual studio 2010

```
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Nguyen Van Dung\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MotionTracking\Debug\MotionTracking.exe', Symbols loaded.
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Norton AntiVirus\NortonData\21.1.0.18\Definitions\BASHDefs\20141118.001\UMEngx86.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opencv_highgui2410.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'MotionTracking.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opencv_core2410.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[3936] MotionTracking.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

How can i solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

that's not an error, the pdb files for the opencv libs are not supplied with the prebuild binaries.

(that just means, you can't step into the opencv code while debugging)

if you need them, recompile opencv from src

---

oh, and you're no more allowed to use IplImages in 2014 !

please use opencv's c++ api, not the deprecated c one.

Comment: I just download OpenCv from it's home webpage.Can you tell me how to compile opencv?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files

Comment: ^^ but keep that for later, you probably don't need it.